# Rewrite Word with capitals

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write RewriteRule rules to select a capital letter word and rewrite to a query. The capital letter word could be in different positions. There are other single capital letters that are to be ignored

An example would be finding the word KELPIE - note it is the only word in full capitals

`http://www.atestdomain.com.au/DogsBigBlackKELPIE.htm`
needs to become
`http://www.atestdomain.com.au/animals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=KELPIE&location_id=2&submit=Search`

Comment: Regex doesn't know English. If the URL was `/FooBarABAZ.htm` it won't be able to know if you want `BAZ` or `ABAZ`. There's a lot of info in that internal URL, is `dogtype` the only parameter that changes? If not, and you have a lot of these URLs, you'd be better off using `RewriteMap`.

Comment: Thanks Walf. I'll investigate RewriteMap however, using ([A-Z]{2,}) I can get the word I need as it will be the only word with more than 1 capital letter. Just having trouble returning the url I need. RewriteRule ([A-Z]{2,})(.*) /animals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=$1&location_id=2&submit=Search returns http://www.atestdomain.com.au/DogsBigBlack/animals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=KELPIE&location_id=2&submit=Search which is nearly correct but should not have /DogsBigBlack/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what you're after.

```
RewriteRule ([A-Z]{2,})\.htm$ animals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=$1&location_‌id=2&submit=Search [NS,NE,B,DPI,L]
```

But, like I said, that still won't be able to differentiate between an uppercase keyword, and one preceded by a single letter word (which looks like it would be uppercased in your scheme).

Comment: Thanks for your response but using http://htaccess.mwl.be/ as a test I still don't get the desired result. RewriteRule ([A-Z]{2,})\.htm$ animals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=$1&location_‌​id=2&submit=Search [NS,NE,B,DPI,L]  still gives me http://www.atestdomain.com.au/DogsBigBlackanimals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=KELPIE&location_‌​id=2&submit=Search.... I need to get rid of DogsBigBlack out of the resultant URL..... Also thanks for the headsup re single letter words, that won't happen as the URLs are generated and there are no single letter words

Comment: How do you even know that's what the result is? In a proper internal rewrite, you never see the URL unless you enable tracing and look through the logs; it'll just go to the right place or 404. If you see that in your address bar, something else is wrong. Do you have other rules you're not showing us?

Comment: using htaccess.mwl.be as a test

Comment: So you didn't try it on an actual server? I did and got `["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=> string(62) "keyword=&category=2&dogtype=KELPIE&location_id=2&submit=Search" ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(19) "/animals/search.php"` with `var_dump($_SERVER);`. That tool is just an emulator, and a buggy one, evidently.

Comment: of course I tried it on the server. i got a 500 error. What worked was RewriteRule [A-Z][a-z]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}[A-Z][a-z]{1,}([A-Z]{2,})\.htm$ animals/search.php?keyword=&category=2&dogtype=$1&location_‌​id=2&submit=Search [NS,NE,B,DPI,L]........ Thanks for your help, would have managed this without your input

Comment: Thank with upvotes and/or answer acceptance. I think the 500 error was due to a non-printing character after the `_` in `location_id` in my answer, but I just copied that part from your question, so no idea where it came from.